# Fetching data from tables whose names are stored in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, mysqli, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table lets say table_names which contains some table names ( table1 , table2 ,table3 etc ). Now I want to fetch the data from table1 , table2 , table3 etc by going through the table table_names.

I am unable to achieve this task. Could anyone please help me out of this situation ?

I am using Oracle DB.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If from TableA you have to get value from **Single** table then use this,

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT table_name FROM tableA WHERE id=3)AS b
```

Otherwise from getting from multiple table, I prefer below PHP-

```
while($a=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query((SELECT table_name FROM tableA)))
{ $tablename=$a[table_name];
while($b=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query((SELECT * FROM $tablename))))
  {
    echo $b[column_name];
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not fetching for front end interactivity. I want to fetch them and apply some (where) conditions and return as a table (view). Like how regular sql queries return.

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
DECLARE
 str VARCHAR2(30);
 num number(5);
BEGIN
SELECT count(*) into num FROM table_names;
FOR i in 1..num loop
SELECT name into str FROM 
(SELECT ROWNUM r,t.name FROM table_names t) where r = i;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM '||str;
str:='';
end loop;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select t1.*,t2.*,t3.* from table1 t1,table2 t2, table3 t3 where (select name from tables)